# xls encoding issue only in safari

Tags: xml, xslt

Below are the xml file and xsl file for my page, there is a href link named "00_Test", when i click it, it should link to "00_Test/summary.xml" (this is read by `<xsl:value-of select="url" />` in xsl file.

OK, all the above works well expcept for safari. In safari, when i click the link,it doese not go to "00_Test/summary.xml", and i find the value is "00_Test/summary.xml%0A%09%09%09".
So who can tell me how can i resolve this issue in safari.

xml file

```
<testsuiteList>
        <testsuite>
            <name>
                00_Test
            </name>
            <url>
                00_Test/summary.xml
            </url>
                ......
```

xsl file

```
<xsl:for-each select="summary/testsuiteList/testsuite">
                <tr>
                    <td nowrap="1">
                    <a>
                      <xsl:attribute name="href">
                      <xsl:value-of select="url" />  
                        .......
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(url)"/>` to make sure leading and trailing white space is stripped. That should do, assuming you don't have `url` values like `<url>dir/file  name.xml</url>` with more than one consecutive space in file or folder names.